# Using D3.js to create a bar chart that transforms on button click by loading tsv data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a bar chart using d3.js in order to show population against different towns, however, I've found that when I try to create a transition between two different sets of data (in tsv format), d3.js won't trigger and fire off the animation to the second set of data. I'm unsure of what I'm doing wrong.

This is the current code I have.

```
<div id="options">
 <button id="set1">2016</button>
 <button onclick="update2021()" id="set2">2021</button>
 <button id="set2">2026</button>
 <button id="set2">2031</button>
 <button id="set2">2036</button>
 <button id="set2">2041</button>
 <button id="set2">2046</button>
 <button id="set2">2050</button>
 <svg width="3000" height="500"></svg>

<script>
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
        width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
        y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

    var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.tsv("sydtest.tsv", function(d) {
      d.population = +d.population;
      return d;
    }, function(error, data) {
      if (error) throw error;

      x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.lga; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.population; })]);

      g.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Y-Axis Code
      g.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
          .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(25))

      g.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.lga); })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.population); })
          .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.population); });
    });

function update2021() {
         // Get the data again
            d3.tsv("sydtest.tsv", function(d) {
              d.population = +d.population;
              return d;
            }, function(error, data) {
              if (error) throw error;

        // Scale the range of the data again 
        x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.lga; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.population; })]);

    // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
    var svg = d3.select("svg").transition();

    // Make the changes
        svg.select(".bar")   // change the line
            data(data)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.lga); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.population); })
            .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
            .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.population); });
        svg.select("axis--x") // change the x axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(g);
        svg.select("axis--y") // change the y axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(g);
    });
}
</script>
```

I've followed some code that has been written previously, and found that I could get the y-axis and x-axis to animate, but the data it self wouldn't actually render on the canvas. From this I deduce that I've probably written the 'transition' part of my code wrong.

If someone can show me if I've implemented the transition code incorrectly, I'd be grateful!

Comment: Does the data render on init?

Comment: Yes it does, you can see the initial data, it just doesn't transition.

Comment: You need to define a key function, otherwise d3 thinks the "new" data is just updated data. Therefore your enter selection is empty.